# Rename Video on upload

Tags: php, file

I have a script which is uploading and saving video's correctly but I want to rename the video before saving.

The page **upload-video.php** ends in `.php?video_id=556`, in this example I want to save the video as 556

```
$video_id=$_GET["video_id"];  
$target_dir = "video_uploads/";
```

And the move script:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$target_file = $target_dir . $video_id;
```

to define the destination properly before your move_script.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

`$target_file` is the name of the file being saved on the server.  You can use whatever value you like there.  So if you want to save it as `556` then you'd use that as the file name.  For example:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], '/path/to/videos/556');
```

Whatever logic you want to use to determine the file name would be the logic you use to build the `$target_file` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$video_id=$_GET["id"];
$path = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "video_uploads/$video_id.$ext"
```